# Is it possible to get query results in an App Insights inline function?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to write an App Insights query that will report back the timespan between two known events, specifically circuit breaker open and close events. The assumption is that these events always occur in pairs, so we need to know the time between the two for every occurrence in a time period.

My first attempt was to use an inline function. Simplified version below.

```
let timeOpened = (timeClosed:datetime)
{
    let result = customEvents
    | where name == 'CircuitBreakerStatusChange'
    | where customDimensions['State'] == 'Open'
    | where timestamp < timeClosed
    | order by timestamp desc
    | take 1
    | project timestamp;
    let scalar = toscalar(result);  
    scalar
};
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(4h)
| where name == 'CircuitBreakerStatusChange'
| where customDimensions['State'] == 'Closed'
| extend timeOpen = timestamp - timeOpened(timestamp)
```

There may be a better way to do this. If so your ideas are welcome! But in this particular attempt the only feedback I get from Azure when running this is "Syntax error". However, I don't believe there's a syntax error here because if I just change the return value of the function from `scalar` to `now()` it runs successfully. Also I can run the body of the function in isolation successfully. Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting syntax error because query language does not allow possibly recursive constructs. Now() worked because it was statically (not dynamically) retrieved at the query time.

I think you may achieve the desired outcome with [serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/serializeoperator) and [prev()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/prevfunction) operators:

```
Table | order by timestamp asc | serialize
| extend previousTime = prev(timestamp,1)
| extend Diff = iff(customDimensions['State'] == 'Closed', timestamp - previousTime, 0)
| where Diff > 0
```

Note: I haven't tested the example above and it may need some additional thought to make it work (e.g. making sure that the previous record is actually "Opened" before doing `previousTime` calculation).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thank you. I wasn't aware of the `prev` function. Unfortunately this doesn't help my specific scenario because my case is complex enough that it's not always the directly previous record that holds my comparison data. I thought maybe I could pass a delegate to the `prev` function so it returns from the previous row that meets a condition but alas, no.